# Java instanceof on interface

Tags: java, interface

I have the following code dealing with command line options:

I have these classes:

```
public enum DwelltimeOptions implements IDwelltimeOptions{

      public DwelltimeOptions findOption(String s){
             return null;
          }
 }

public interface IDwelltimeOptions extends IOptions{

    public void compare(ReconToolCompare rtc) throws ReconToolException;

}
public interface IOptions {

    public IOptions findOption(String s);

}
```

the problem is that my firstOption variable below doesn't appear to be an instanceof IOptions, even though I believe it should be.

```
Object firstOption = null;
        try {
             firstOption = Class.forName("com.nim.tools.options."  + capitalize(args.get(0)) + "Options");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(firstOption instanceof IOptions){
        secondOption = ((IOptions) firstOption).findOption(args.get(1).substring(1));
        }
        else{
            ReconTool.logError("Unrecognized option: \"" + args.get(0) + "\"");
            ReconTool.printOutOptions();
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

firstOption variable is "class com.nim.tools.options.DwelltimeOptions" and the DwelltimeOptions class implements IDwelltimeOptions which extends IOptions...so DwelltimeOptions should be an instance of IOptions.

Actually, I think I just realized the problem. firstOption variable is actually a Class object and can't be used in an instanceof context and can't be compared with an Interface such as IOptions?

Comment: That's right. `Class.forName` returns a `Class` object.

Comment: Right, you need to make `firstOption = Class.forName("yada yada").newInstance();` if you want to check it with `instanceOf`.

Comment: @azurefrog `IOption` is an interface, so you cannot create a new instance using this approach.

Comment: But he's not getting the class for an `IOption`, he's getting the class for a `DwelltimeOptions` which implements that interface.  You can't new instance an enum?

Comment: @azurefrog oh, didn't read that part of the question.

Comment: yeah I don't think you can call newIntance() on an enum, but I'd have to double check.

Answer (score 2):

[`Class#forName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-) returns an instance of `Class<?>`, so in this code:

```
firstOption = Class.forName("com.nim.tools.options."  + capitalize(args.get(0)) + "Options");
```

If the argument you pass in `args.get(0)` is `I` and you have `IOptions`, then `firstOption` is the same as `Class<IOption>` and not an instance of an object that implements `IOption` interface.

> firstOption variable is actually a Class object and can't be used in an instanceof context and can't be compared with an Interface such as IOptions

Yes, your assumption is right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [`Class.forName` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-) returns a `Class` object representing the class, not an instance of the class.  So the only thing `instanceof` will return `true` for is `Class` (and `Object`).  If you want to know if the class implements an interface (or a superclass), and you have the relevant `Class` objects, then you can use [`Class`'s `isAssignableFrom` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-).

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter. It returns true if so; otherwise it returns false.

```
if (IOptions.class.isAssignableFrom(firstOption)) {
```